# spring excel POI Apache set cell value text alignment center

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-poi

i want to align center in header0 on Cell Value "testing testing"

```
val style = workbook.createCellStyle()
            style.borderTop = 24.toShort() // double lines border
            style.borderBottom = 24.toShort() // single line border
            val font = workbook.createFont()
            font.fontHeightInPoints = 15.toShort()
            font.boldweight = XSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD
            style.setFont(font)
            style.borderRight = 6.toShort()
            style.borderLeft = 6.toShort()

            var rowNum = 11
            var rowNumber = 1

            header0.createCell(0).setCellValue("TESTING TESTING")
```

cell value will be align center

Comment: First update your Apache POI version to something more current. Your code shows using an **very** ancient Apache POI version. Then [CellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment align)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setAlignment-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment-) using [HorizontalAlignment.CENTER](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/HorizontalAlignment.html#CENTER).

Comment: but in my case use poi 3.12 
 "      header0.createCell(0).cellStyle.alignment=CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER
            header0.createCell(0).setCellValue("BIDANG ANGKUTAN JALAN DISHUB JATIM")
            header1.createCell(0).setCellValue("Lembar Muatan Bus ( LMB )")

"
if i use header0.createCell(0).cellStyle.alignment=CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER changes all to the center of all. I want to make it the value that I want

Comment: Cell styles of Excel cells are shared. So the cell style of your cell `header0` míght be shared with many other cells. So if you get the cell style of that cell and change it, then you change it for all cells which use that shared style. If only that one cell shall be center aligned, then it would need it's own cell style.